# In XSLT, How do I split the text content of an element into lines?

Tags: string, xslt, character

I'm using XSLT to parse the textual content of an XML element. This text contains newlines, but I can't seem to parse them correctly. I'm using code I found online to chop up the text. Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
<xsl:variable name="first">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($source, $newline)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="rest">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($source, $newline)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

This is part of a recusrive template that pushes $rest into itself.

The problem is that the code sample doesn't define $newline.
If I set $newline to a letter, like 's', the text gets split up just fine (e.g. it will turn the input "resounding" into "re" and "ounding"). But when I try to set $newline to the newline character, that is `&#xa;` or `&#xa0;`, it recurses forever and gives me a stack overflow. I also tried to define an ENTITY for newline but it makes no difference.

The input has ordinary CR/LF at the end of each line (I'm on a Windows box).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use EXSLT try with [str:tokenize](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html)

```
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($source, $newline)">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or similarly with XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($source, $newline)">
  <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Sadly, I have neither. I'm calling XSLT from an Ant script.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this template once. It is a named template so you can call it where ever you need it. The text here is split up in 70 character pieces:

```
<xsl:template name="Texts">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="TEXTITEM" />
    <xsl:param name="line-length" select="70"/>
    <xsl:variable name="line" select="substring($string,1,$line-length)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rest" select="substring($string, $line-length+1)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$line">
        <MYTEXT> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$line"/>  
        </MYTEXT> 
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$rest">
        <xsl:call-template name="Texts">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$rest"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="line-length" select="$line-length"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the new line character: Try using "0x0d 0x0a" which is ASCII CR+LF. So $newline="0x0d 0x0a" Best regards, Peter

Comment: This chops it up into chunks of equal length, which is not what I need. What I actually want to achieve is find out which of the lines is the longest.

Comment: If I set $newline to the value 0x0d0x0a, $first and $rest both become empty. Same if I set it to \n or \n\r. Or if I say

Comment: --or if I just hit enter. inside the xsl:variable tag.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/str">
                <str>
                    <xsl:call-template name="strSplit">
                        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="seqno" select="1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </str>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="strSplit">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:param name="seqno"/>

        <xsl:variable name="afterLeadingWS"
            select="substring-after($str, substring-before($str,substring-before(normalize-space($str), ' ')))"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')">
                <line>
                    <xsl:attribute name="seqno"><xsl:value-of select="$seqno"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="length"><xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;'))"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')"/>
                </line>
                <xsl:call-template name="strSplit">
                    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="seqno" select="$seqno + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <line>
                    <xsl:attribute name="seqno"><xsl:value-of select="$seqno"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$afterLeadingWS"/>
                </line>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <str>
        yigifgniuq  h 
        eukwgf kuew hgk.uhgku
        ,/v.,silghouihhg
    </str>
    <str>
        09734ymmnyr n.0808
        o149013483ymr7rg
        738924m c0 

    </str>
</root>
```

the output result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <str>
        <line seqno="1" length="13">yigifgniuq  h </line>
        <line seqno="2" length="21">eukwgf kuew hgk.uhgku</line>
        <line seqno="3" length="18">        ,/v.,silghouihhg</line>
        <line seqno="4">    </line>
    </str>
    <str>
        <line seqno="1" length="18">09734ymmnyr n.0808</line>
        <line seqno="2" length="16">o149013483ymr7rg</line>
        <line seqno="3" length="11">738924m c0 </line>
        <line seqno="4" length="2">     </line>
        <line seqno="5">    </line>
    </str>
</root>
```

Note that leading tabs (or blanks) are seen as part of lines.

Comment: This looks very helpful... but instead of outputting the tokenized lines, I want to know the length of the longest line.

Comment: add another attribute thus:  <xsl:attribute name="length"><xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;'))"/></xsl:attribute> - see edit above

Comment: Amazing, I was able to modify this to split a raw address (separated by new lines) into `<Address1>blah</Address1><Address2>...`

Answer (score 2):

Maestro13's answer brought me closest, and I ended up merging the template I had with his, to produce this, which I share here for future generations. It's a template that returns the length of the longest line in the string you pass to it.

```
<xsl:template name="longestCodeLine">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>

    <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Is this the last line? -->
    <xsl:when test="contains($str, '&#xA;')">
        <!-- No. First isolate all remaining lines, and recurse to find its longest line. -->
        <xsl:variable name="bestOfTheRest">
            <xsl:call-template name="longestCodeLine">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str, '&#xA;')"/>                        
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Compare the longest of the remaining lines to this one. Which one's longer? -->
            <!-- If the longest of the remaining lines is longer, return that line. -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length($bestOfTheRest) &gt; string-length(substring-before($str, '&#xA;'))">
                <xsl:value-of select="$bestOfTheRest"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- If this line longer, return this line. -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
    <!-- If there are no \n's left, this is your last string. So it is by definition the longest one left. -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Mathijs, Thank you for sharing your final code. I will look into that and also the difference between "#xA;" and "0x0a" is not clear to me. I have to follow up on that too. Best regards, Peter +1

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd add a line splitting code that adds newlines after white space.

```
<xsl:function name="kode:splitLongLine">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="regex">
   <xsl:text>(((.){1,55})( |$))</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="result">
   <xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="{$regex}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1),'&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('REPORT ERROR: ', .)"/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
   </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
 </xsl:function>
```